# How are offsets reset in kafka 0.11

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka 0.11. I'm trying to reset the offset of a topic in a consumer group but don't see consistency among the option. How is the offset calculated for different options in kafka-consumer-groups?

```
$ /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxxxxxxxxxxx.devkafka.com:9092 --group testgroup --reset-offsets **--by-duration PT1H30M0S** --topic Test_Upgrade --export --command-config client.properties 2>/dev/null
**Test_Upgrade,1,615
Test_Upgrade,0,625**

$ date
**Thu May 31 15:30:45 BST 2018**

$ /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-3.0.0-1.3.0.0.p0.40/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxxxxxxxxxxx.devkafka.com:9092 --group testgroup --reset-offsets **--to-datetime 2018-05-31T14:00:00.000** --topic Test_Upgrade --export --command-config client.properties 2>/dev/null
**Test_Upgrade,1,754
Test_Upgrade,0,772**
```

Answer (score 0):

`--to-datetime` - when we want to reset offsets to an specific point in time. (e.g. to 1/1/2017 at 00:00 to reprocess all records from these year)
`--by-duration` - when we want to go back some period ago (e.g. P7D to reprocess all records from one week ago)

Taken from here [KIP-122](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling)

To actually run it, you need to add `--execute` to your command, without it Kafka prints the result of the operation.

More info in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b)